# Defining and Declaring global variable in C++

Tags: c++, global-variables

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace as std;

int x;
x=10;

int main()
{
 cout<<x<<endl;
 return 0
}
```

This gives an error, but if I use:

```
int x=10;
```

instead of:

```
int x;
x=10;
```

It works fine. **Can anyone point out the issue?** The compiler reads error:

> expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the body of function you can only declare (int x;) or declare and initialize (int x = 10;) variables. Here you were trying to assign a value (x=10;) to variable that was declared before.

Comment: if I write int x; x=10; inside the main (), then it works. So do you mean the thing you said above only applies to global variable.

Comment: Yes, it applies only to global variables. Only global variables can be declared outside the body of main() or other function.